# Better looking waiting room UI for google games

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm creating a game using google play services.  When players are waiting to connect to others, they are in a waiting room UI like so:

[image]

As you can see the default waiting room UI is very basic and does not happen to visually fit the theme of my game at all.  I would like to change the backgrounds of different elements in that UI, but the layout's definition is not exposed anywhere that I can see. Is there a way to edit the layout for the waiting room?

I'm using the code from their sample app "ButtonClicker2000" found here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

The method for showing the waiting room is here:

```
// Show the waiting room UI to track the progress of other players as they enter the
// room and get connected.
void showWaitingRoom(Room room) {
    // minimum number of players required for our game
    // For simplicity, we require everyone to join the game before we start it
    // (this is signaled by Integer.MAX_VALUE).
    final int MIN_PLAYERS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, MIN_PLAYERS);

    // show waiting room UI
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}
```

Comment: If you can explain why you're downvoting I'd appreciate it.  Asking if it's possible to modify the default waiting room ui when using google play services seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: Please remove the downvotes or explain what I can do to improve my question.

Answer (score -1):

you need tou use android:background in the xml file 
for color : `android:background="@color/white"`
for img   :  `android:background="@drawable/background"`

Comment: I don't see anywhere that the layout for that ui is exposed.  or anywhere to set it with my own.